# Email to run a bash script

Tags: email, scripting, shell-scripting

I have a bash script to restart a service that runs every 3am to guarantee that the service isn't crashed when users require it. However, I need to provide a simpler way for my partner (that isn't from IT area) to run this script when something go wrong.

Is there any way to configure this script to run when a email is sent to some address?

Comment: As an aside, you can looking into things like Monit to keep services up, instead of relying on some sort of human intervention (via some duct-tape-and-baling-wire scripts).

Comment: I'd DEFINITELY look into configuring Monit rather than relying on a rube-goldberg-esque solution that requires a non-tech person to keep things running. Monit not only can give you the status of services, but can restart them *for* you when the service actually fails and notify you that it has failed.

Comment: If you can use monit then you can use cron - although monit is much more sophisticated than cron tehre is a learning curve there. If you can configure your MTA to handle emails like this then you should be able to configure cron to do the same - which will be much *MUCH* safer.

Comment: I was able to configure Monit and it really solved my problem! It not just allow me to restart the service in a simple click of button, but it does a much better job: it monitors the process for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely!

In your /etc/aliases file, do this:

```
servicerestart: |/usr/local/bin/kickservice
```

... where the email will be sent to `servicerestart@yourdomain.com` and the script you've written is the path above. The email and all the headers will be passed to the `stdin` of your script which you can process as needed (look for password, etc.)

Comment: This presumes he is running an MTA locally.

Answer (score 2):

If the MTA obeys a ~/.forward file, then you can have [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/) process the incoming mail and run a script as soon as the message arrives.

See http://www.panix.com/~elflord/unix/procmail.html

For one of my accounts, I have the following ~/.procmailrc

```
# procmail tutorial: http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue14/procmail.html

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
MAILDIR=$HOME/Mail
DEFAULT=$HOME/Mail/inbox
LOGFILE=$HOME/procmail.`date +%Y-%m`.log
SHELL=/usr/bin/ksh

MY_XLOOP='X-Loop: user@example.com'
MY_RECIPIENT='mailing_list@example.com'


#############################################################################
# 3rd party request processing
# send a copy of the message to the processing script, and carry on
# with the next recipe

:0c
* ^From:.*@3rdparty\.invalid
* ^Subject:.*ABC/DEF.*(Request|Access|Approval)
| $HOME/bin/process_request_email.pl | \
  mailx -s "3rd party request results" $MY_RECIPIENT


#############################################################################
# forward all mail to mailing list
:0
* ! ^$MY_XLOOP
{
    # add a header
    # 'f' = filter: continue processing results of program
    # 'w' = wait for program to return
    # 'h' = pass message headers to program
    :0fwh
    | formail -A "$MY_XLOOP"

    # then forward the message
    # 'c' = send a copy to recipient and continue processing
    :0c
    ! $MY_RECIPIENT
}

# if we get here, then the message has an X-Loop header.
# let it fall into $DEFAULT
```

Comment: If the local MTA obeys a .forward-file, you don't ***need*** procmail: just forward directly to a script.

Comment: but procmail allows you to add additional logic like forwarding a copy to a mailbox, avoiding mail loops, and validating the origin / authenticating the email - which is pretty essential if you expose functionality like this via email.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.

You need:

- an MTA to receive these mails,
- a processor to process the mail,
- rules and restrictions to make sure it can't be abused (easily)

Based on the requirements, I would advise [**postfix**](http://www.postfix.org/) as the MTA; it has built-in capabilities to execute scripts on message reception, plus easy to configure restrictions on mail reception and connectivity.

Of course, most sysadmins would just configure **cron**.

Comment: I'll take a look on postfix! Regarding cron, I'm using this to run the script on schedule (every 3am). Is it also useful for this email question?

Comment: No, but you provide no information as to why this doesn't work for you.